# Nominatim returns only the exact match

Tags: php, api, geolocation, laravel-5.3, openstreetmap

Nominatim shows exact match but i need the partial results also. I tried many approach but couldn't make it work. I need your help so badly.
[Here is link of the post which I share in Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/openstreetmap-return-only-the-exact-match)

Comment: I corrected your question. You are asking about Nominatim, not OpenStreetMap.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Nominatim is not able to find partly matching objects. However you can take a look at other [OSM-based search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines). As far as I know [Photon](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Photon) is able to perform non-exact searches.